# Android Ble status code 14 in onCharacteristicwrite

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an app using BLE where i have to send some commands to peripheral device to get response. Write characteristics code is written below:

```
    public void writeCustomCharacteristic(String value) {
        this.value = "";
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        /*check if the service is available on the device*/
        BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID);
        if (mCustomService == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
            return;
        }

        /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(CHARACTERSTICS_UUID);
        mWriteCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(value.getBytes());


        if (!mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
        }
    }
```

And after write characteristics i got response in following method here it returns status code 14, which is not mentioned in official document as well:

```
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        System.out.println("BluetoothLeService.onCharacteristicWrite");

        System.out.println(BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS + " :status: " + status);            

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Status code 14 probably means ATT error code 14, which is defined in Bluetooth Core specification v5.0, Vol 3, Part F, section 3.4.1.1 Table 3.3.

This error code is sent from the remote device so it's most likely no error on the Android side. Error code 14 in ATT means "Unlikely Error". You need to investigate why the remote device sends this error code.

Comment: I am not able to find why remote device returns this error. Actually all commands is working fine except one which unlock the remote device. Could you please explain more so that i can find out the exact issue.

Comment: You're basically asking the BLE version of "why does my web server return 500 Internal Server Error? Here is the code for making the http request" :). It's impossible to answer that question with no further info about how the server is programmed.

Comment: I am using pearly device as a remote device.

There are following commands which i send to remote device:
1. "?" for communication test with remote device
2. "~K?" for generate key from the remote device.
3. send the received key to my server to get new which will unlock the further commands on remote device.

whenever i execute 3rd step then i get status code 14 error

Comment: i am sending "~KEQ4doAMZ%lwIV8hRu3HcSp4CcOpZCc" this type of key to remote device