# React Native BLE Manager (Android) status code 14 on write to characteristic

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using the react native ble manager package to build a react native app that communicates with a python client over BLE.

When writing to a characteristic on Android (this bug does not seem to appear on IOS) the write is successful but shortly after it I receive this error:

```
ERROR Error writing eeee2a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb status=14
```

This is the simplified code that handles connecting, notifications and writing on the Android side:

```
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter, Platform } from 'react-native'
import BleManager, { Peripheral } from 'react-native-ble-manager'
import { END } from 'redux-saga'
import { bytesToString } from 'convert-string'

const UPDATE_SERVICE_UUID = '0000180d-aaaa-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'

export const Characteristic =
   {
        WIFI_STATUS_UUID: 'bbbb2a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
        WIFI_CREDS_UUID: 'aaaa2a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
        VERSION_UUID: 'cccc2a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
        UPDATE_STATUS_UUID: 'dddd2a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
        DO_UPDATE_UUID: 'eeee2a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
        ERROR_UUID: 'ffff2a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
      }

class BLEManager {
  bleManagerModule: any
  bleManagerEmitter: any
  scanning: boolean
  dispatch: any
  stopScanListener: any
  peripheralDiscoverListener: any
  characteristicUpdateListener: any
  onDisconnectListener: any
  connectTimeout: any

  constructor() {
    BleManager.start({ showAlert: false })

    this.bleManagerModule = NativeModules.BleManager
    this.bleManagerEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(this.bleManagerModule)
    this.scanning = false
  }

  startScan = (onPeripheralFound: (peripheral: Peripheral | null) => void) => {
    if (!this.scanning) {
      BleManager.scan([], 3, true)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Scanning...')
          this.scanning = true
          this.peripheralDiscoverListener = this.bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
            'BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral',
            onPeripheralFound,
          )

          this.stopScanListener = this.bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
            'BleManagerStopScan',
            () => {
              onPeripheralFound(END)
            },
          )
          return
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err)
        })
    } else {
      console.log('already scanning')
    }
    return () => {
      console.log('stopped scanning')
      this.peripheralDiscoverListener.remove()
      this.stopScanListener.remove()
    }
  }

  getBondedDevices = (onGetBondedPeripherals: any) => {
    BleManager.getBondedPeripherals().then(bondedPeripheralsArray => {
      onGetBondedPeripherals(bondedPeripheralsArray)
      // TODO: is the END message here necessary?
      onGetBondedPeripherals(END)
      return
    })
    return () => {}
  }

  connectToPeripheral = async (peripheralID: string) => {
    try {
      await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        this.connectTimeout = setTimeout(reject, 3000)

        console.log('connecting to ' + peripheralID)

        try {
          await BleManager.connect(peripheralID)
          await BleManager.retrieveServices(peripheralID)
        } catch (error) {
          reject()
        }

        if (this.connectTimeout) {
          clearTimeout(this.connectTimeout)

          this.connectTimeout = null

          this.onDisconnectListener = this.bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
            'BleManagerDisconnectPeripheral',
            this.onDisconnectPeripheral,
          )

          resolve()
        }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      clearTimeout(this.connectTimeout)

      this.connectTimeout = null

      console.error('Could not connect to device.')

      throw new Error(err)
    }

    return
  }

  watchForCharacteristicsUpdates = async (
    updateCharValue: (arg0: { payload: any }) => void,
    peripheralID: string,
  ) => {
    try {
      await BleManager.startNotification(
        peripheralID,
        UPDATE_SERVICE_UUID,
        Characteristic.ERROR_UUID,
      )
      await BleManager.startNotification(
        peripheralID,
        UPDATE_SERVICE_UUID,
        Characteristic.VERSION_UUID,
      )
      await BleManager.startNotification(
        peripheralID,
        UPDATE_SERVICE_UUID,
        Characteristic.UPDATE_STATUS_UUID,
      )
    } catch (e) {
      updateCharValue(new Error(e))
      console.error(e)
    }

    console.log('watch for notifications')

    this.characteristicUpdateListener = this.bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
      'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic',
      ({ value, characteristic }) => {
        // Convert bytes array to string
        const data = bytesToString(value)

        console.log(
          `Received ${data} (${value}) for characteristic ${characteristic}`,
        )

        updateCharValue({
          payload: {
            characteristic: characteristic,
            data: data,
          },
        })
      },
    )
  }

  disconnectFromPeripheral = async (peripheralID: string) => {
    await BleManager.disconnect(peripheralID)
    this.characteristicUpdateListener.remove()
  }

  onDisconnectPeripheral = (peripheralID: string) => {
    console.log(peripheralID + ' disconnected')
    this.onDisconnectListener.remove()
  }

  checkIfConnected = async (peripheralID: string) => {
    return await BleManager.isPeripheralConnected(peripheralID, [])
  }

  triggerUpdateCheck = async (peripheralID: string) => {
    return await BleManager.write(
      peripheralID,
      UPDATE_SERVICE_UUID,
      Characteristic.WIFI_STATUS_UUID,
      [1],
    )
  }

  runUpdate = async (peripheralID: string) => {
    return await BleManager.write(
      peripheralID,
      UPDATE_SERVICE_UUID,
      Characteristic.DO_UPDATE_UUID,
      [1],
    )
  }
}

const bleManager = new BLEManager()

export default bleManager
```

I've researched this a bit and it seems that some people have the problem but I could not find an explanation or solution to it.

I'm even unsure where to start debugging. Any suggestions are welcome.

**Details:**

- Device: [Pixel 6]
- OS: [Android 12]
- react-native-ble-manager version: ^8.4.1
- react-native version: 0.67.4

Note: I've also asked this question on Github: https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/issues/887

Comment: The answer for [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254735/android-ble-status-code-14-in-oncharacteristicwrite) suggests a problem with your peripheral. Is your python code giving some error messages? Where is the code running? Maybe you could get some system logs

Comment: I've seen this post in the meantime as well and tested some stuff. So far I ran the python counterpart on my laptop as well as the intended raspberry pi and both produce the error but no obvious error message on the side of the python script. What systems logs would you have a look at?

Comment: So you have a GATT client written in python and you run a GATT server on Android which returns "unlikely error" to the python client? You could start by showing the code on Android where you handle the write request.

Comment: I've added the android code.

Comment: Ok you have it the other way around it seems. Your Android code acts as a GATT client and your python code implements a GATT server, which you are trying to write to (DO_UPDATE_UUID). If your GATT server returns an error, then that's where you should investigate why that happens.

Comment: It is a Bluez bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386303/receiving-err-unlikely-when-doing-a-write-with-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as mentioned by Martijn) was the bug in Bluez which is fixed in 5.65. Simply upgrading and clearing the Bluetooth cache fixed it.